# No internet on Apple TV, if Samsung monitor isn't connected

Tags: networking, router, internet

I have the following setup:

Router from my ISP connected to a Google WiFi point.
The Google WiFi point is in charge of DHCP.
The WiFi point is connected to a switch that is patching up my house.

My laptop (Macbook Pro M1, 2021) is connected to a Samsung LS34A650U monitor via USB-C.
The Samsung monitor is connected to ethernet via cable from a wall socket, and my laptop gets internet through the USB-C cable.

Separately I have an Apple TV connected to internet via cable in a wall socket.

When I disconnect the USB-C from my laptop, the Apple TV loses its internet (DHCP lease). It will eventually get a self-assigned IP, but no actual internet.

If I remove the internet cable from the Apple TV, and let it connect via WiFi, it works.

If I connect a different laptop to the Samsung monitor, everything still works.

If I disconnect the monitor from the internet wall socket, everything still works.

---

What's going on?! And how can I fix it or troubleshoot further?

Comment: Sounds almost like you have more than one device running DHCP.

Comment: There's no problem on a day-to-day basis. The internet disappears only if I disconnect the USB-C cable from my laptop.